# Who did Kylo Ren think Rey was in "The Force Awakens"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker

**contains spoilers for *The Force Awakens*, *The Last Jedi*, and *The Rise of Skywalker***

I know there have been questions such as "Why was Kylo wrong about Rey's parentage," but I'm not asking about that.  I guess I'm looking for an answer here that would be either from the disjointed movies or J.J. Abrams' original plan.

It seemed established from *The Force Awakens* that Rey was someone of importance.  A very significant scene that hinted that her parentage was known to Kylo was when an officer told him that BB-8 was with a girl.  Kylo instantly Force-chokes the officer and asks "What girl?" in a tone implying that he knows a girl who would be involved in such a situation.  This fed into the theory that she was Kylo's twin sister or cousin, who he knew previously but assumed dead or missing.

In *The Last Jedi*, Kylo tells Rey that her parents were no one, but it is told in *The Rise of Skywalker* that this information was incorrect.  It is only when, at the beginning of *The Rise of Skywalker*, asking Palpatine, that Kylo learns the truth of Rey's parentage.

So - what was that reaction in *The Force Awakens*?  Was Rey originally supposed to be related to Kylo?  What was the reason for his Force-choking and anger upon hearing of a "girl?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Kylo Ren knew Rey before Star Wars: The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178866/how-kylo-ren-knew-rey-before-star-wars-the-force-awakens)

Comment: It might be the wrong thing to do, but it felt wrong to close this as duplicate of a question that's at -4.  Plus this one is better written.

Comment: “J.J. Abrams' original plan” — like his plan for what the island was in *Lost!* He definitely had one, all mapped out!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I heard that even *Felicity*'s ending makes no sense. And that's a teenage romance show!

Comment: Not adding as an answer since it's total conjecture, but... it's possible Kylo knew that Rey was Palpatine's granddaughter from the moment he looked into her mind, or as part of their force bond. But he told her that her parents were nobodies because (a) that's true (it's her *grandparent* who is special!), and (b) selectively revealing only that information  fit his goals at the time.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the scene: having just beaten up a defenceless wall of instruments, Kylo Ren pauses and asks if there's anything else. And having just thrown a temper-tantrum over having received some bad news and managed to get ahold of himself, just then the officer then says, oh yeah, sorry, more bad news, some chick in the desert apparently wandered off with a droid carrying the information.

And now, having found out that there was even more interference in his plans from some random woman, he simply snapped. If the officer had said the droid had gone off with some man, or another droid, the same scene would have played out with the appropriate replacement of word in the question "WHAT ____?!"

Answer (score 5):

Good question. There are suggestions, though I don't think there were any canonical answers, that Kylo Ren was "fully" aware of Rey's link to himself and the emperor.

In Force Awakens, Kylo Ren tried to pull the info directly from Rey's mind... He was able to get "the island", then Rey pushed him out, and for a moment, he was shocked.

Perhaps he was able to pull what Rey though was repressed truth from the bottom of her mind... that her parents really were nobody that left her behind... in her mind. Which was obviously, not the whole truth.

I don't see the force-choke scene meaning more than Kylo Ren throwing a temper tantrum.